# Is array error possibly a PHP version issue?

Tags: php, arrays, version

I work on a website that, since last Oct, has had the following lines of code that work just fine:

```
if(empty($post_types))  
{ 
  $post_types[] = 'post';         
  $post_types[] = 'product-list';
}
```

I had not seen this construct in PHP before, (and since I started my programming work in C, it's a little irritating), but it works.

We started a second site with the same technology and basic setup that threw the following error at the same lines of code,

> "Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings ..."

The sites are hosted at the same place, but I noticed that they are using different 7.x versions of PHP. I did a bit of research to see if the behavior is due to a change in PHP 7.3, but I didn't find an answer.

Please note that my question is on whether this situation is possibly a PHP version issue, not how to solve the array problem, which I changed with

```
$post_types = array('post', 'product-list');
```

Comment: No not a version issue, maybe you didn't have error reporting on in the other environment? https://3v4l.org/jdZFt It means that you have defined `$post_types` as a string and then attempt to append an array element onto it as if it was an array.

Comment: maybe u are using `$post_types` somewhere else as a string

Comment: This syntax has been alright since PHP 5.4, so it's probably due to something else? https://3v4l.org/rIJas

Comment: `display_errors` or `error_reporting` differences in php.ini, check with `ini_get`.  But fix the error regardless.

Comment: @Loek: Totally different issue.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I see yes, nice catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your answer in the PHP docs [Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> ```
> $arr[key] = value;
> $arr[] = value;
> // key may be an integer or string
> // value may be any value of any type
> ```
>
> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an
>   alternative way to create an array. This practice is however
>   discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string
>   from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and []
>   may actually stand for string access operator. It is always better to
>   initialize a variable by a direct assignment.
>
> **Note: As of PHP 7.1.0, applying the empty index operator on a string throws a fatal error. Formerly, the string was silently converted to
>   an array.**

So it appears there is a change in PHP 7.1.0 matching with the problem you described.

In your code, your $post_type variable must be initialized as a string [EDIT : I could only reproduce the problem with an empty string], and was previously ( PHP < 7.1.0) silently converted to an array.

Comment: That's strange as both show much earlier http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/066dd2288b850ea5e0cb147e30b92ad627528eed and https://3v4l.org/jdZFt

Comment: @AbraCadaver I think I got it, when trying with an empty initialization: $post_types = '';

Comment: I added the if statement to my question for clarity.